# limitando um campo de datas a apenas números

Tags: php, javascript, html

Atualmente meu campos está desta forma:

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento) {
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i)
  if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
    documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="got" method="GET" action="diar.hist.php" name="troca" onsubmit="return verifica()">
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

Se o usuário digita somente os números, ele completa perfeitamente com as barras, todavia se o usuário digita letras ou símbolos ele aceita da mesma forma. Queria limitar o usuário a digitar apenas números e que formatasse em formato de data conforme o mesmo digita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta acrescentar o código abaixo que verifica o valor hexadecimal da tecla pressionada, se o valor não for correspondente a um número ele não insere o que foi teclado:

```
if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Segue um exemplo de uso abaixo:

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento) {
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i);
  if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
  if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
    documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="got" method="GET" action="diar.hist.php" name="troca" onsubmit="return verifica()">
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Data" name="Data_dd" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Caraca, perfeito, atende o que eu quero, muito obrigado @Phelipe